# Highlight non-breaking space in VIM, different behavior between command and .vimrc

Tags: vim

I want non-breaking space to be immediatly highlighted when I type one in VIM, because my keyboard's layout makes me sometimes write non-breaking space instead of normal space, and then it's a hard time debugging.

I found a cool trick, entering the command :

```
:syntax match ErrorMsg " "
```

does exactly what I want (the space between quotes is a non-breaking space)

Now when I add this command to `.vimrc` (without the beginning colon) it doesn't work… any idea?

Comment: Make sure it is after the colorscheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May depend on how you are entering it into `.vimrc`, but try:

```
au VimEnter,BufWinEnter * syn match ErrorMsg " "
```

Personally I think it would make more sense to map the typing of that space to the <kbd>Space</kbd> -- how often do you need to type a non-breaking space?  Or maybe you can fix the issue at its source: the keyboard layout.

Comment: great ! I have no idea what your command does but it works :) I prefer not change my layout, for other situations I appreciate having the non-breaking space

Answer (score 2):

A custom highlight rule can be used

```
highlight NonBreakingSpace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match NonBreakingSpace / / " (CTRL+V x a 0)
```

Note that `NonBreakingSpace` is an arbitrary rule name. The pattern passed to `match` is what actually finds the *nbsp* character.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Neovim with the nvim-treesitter syntax highlighting plugin, `syn match` will not work but the same behavior can be achieved with:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight BreakspaceChar ctermbg=red guibg=#f92672
autocmd BufWinEnter * call matchadd('BreakspaceChar', ' ')
```